# jQuery Tools Dateinput with live function

Tags: jquery, datepicker, live

I am using jQuery Tools Dateinput script http://jquerytools.org/demos/dateinput/index.html for date picker.

```
$('.inputDate').dateinput({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
```

I am cloning this input field so I have to use live function. Currently, after cloning I am using this function

```
    $('.dateDiv:last').find('.inputDate').dateinput({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
```

It works perfectly fine but I was just wondering if I can use something like this

```
$('.inputDate').live('focus', function(){
   ???
});
```

Comment: Just as a general note, taken from the jQuery documentation: *As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().*

Comment: OK then. .on() is also acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this

```
$('input.datePick').live('focusin', function() {
   $(this).datetime(); 
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I knew that it was something easy like that. Thanks.